# Множина від мета, але не цілі

Tags: вживання-слів, відмінювання

Чи можна/варто казати

> - У мене стільки **мет**.
> - Спринт повинен мати мету або, в окремих випадках, **мети**  спринта

у значенні

> - Я маю так багато **цілей**.
> - Спринт повинен мати ціль або, в окремих випадках, **цілі**  спринта

?

Був дуже здивований коли відкопав у [словнику](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0), що слово мета має множину і його відмінюють по усім відмінкам

```
Називнивний Мети
Родовий     Мет
Давальний   Метам
Знахідний   Мет
Орудний     Метами
Місцевий    на/у Метах
Кличний     Мети
```

Чи можливе/притаманне/доцільне вживання множини слова **мета** в українській мові.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ось що про це пише Є. Д. ЧАК в своїй роботі "[Складні випадки українського слововживання](http://litmisto.org.ua/?p=21107)":

> Мета. У всіх стилях літературної мови, **крім художнього, слово мета
>   вживається тільки в однині**.
>
> У поезії допускається і множинна форма. Порівн.:
>
> **У золотому сяйві мет** Ми йдем напружено вперед (В. Сосюра).
>
> **Підводиться володар мет**, горою піднімає груди (Л. Первомайський).

На сайті [блогу платфоми](http://21tsmay.wixsite.com/acupofthins/single-post/2015/09/29/%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%A2%D0%90-%D0%A6%D0%86%D0%9B%D0%AC-%D0%97%D0%90%D0%92%D0%94%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%9D%D0%AF-%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%91%D0%A3%D0%84%D0%9C%D0%9E-%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%97%D0%86%D0%91%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%98%D0%A1%D0%AF) Wixsite (хоч джерело, звичайно, не можна вважати 100% надійнийм) наткнувся на цікаву думку:

> Тобто, мета - це щось єдине, чого можеш і прагнеш досягти (тому
>   множини не має), а цілі бувають різними та їх кількість не знає меж.

І згідно до цієї теорії - мета - це щось глобальне, яке складається з різних менших цілей.Таку ж саму думку зустрів на [Лінгвофорумі](https://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=3861.0).

Чи можна сказати "мет"? Очевидно, що так, бо як ви вже написали у питанні - форму множини можна знайти у словнику (хоча не у всіх, бо, наприклад, [Вікісловник не подає множину до слова "мета")](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0#%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0), але як бачимо така форма є прийнятна лише для художнього стилю.

Answer (score 2):

В [словнику відмінків](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0) вказана множина слова "мета"

[image]

[Орфографічний словник української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/35/53404/114966.html)

> мета́  іменник жіночого роду 
>   * Але: дві, три, чотири мети́

В СУМ-20 також вказано, що слова "мета" має множину

> [мета](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=50710&page=1605) МЕТА́, и́, ж. Те, до чого хтось прагне, чого хоче досягти;
>   ціль (у 2 знач.).

отже, важаю можна використовувати множину слова "мета"